# object not forming correctly when I create a dict object

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7

I have part of a Python function that looks like:

```
for item in passedList:
    tempDict = {}
    tempDict ["first"] = item[0]
    tempDict ["second"] = item[1]
    tempDict ["third"] = item[2]
```

What I'm expecting back is:

```
{'first': 'item1', 'second': 'item2', 'third': 'item3'}
```

However, I get:

```
{'second': 'item2', 'first': 'item1', 'third': 'item3'}
```

It is probably a pretty simple oversight, but any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the [implementation of dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) in Python is a hashmap or hash table, which doesn't store the elements in order.

You could use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to get around this.

Comment: would OrderedDict alphabetize 'first', 'second', 'third'?

Comment: @Fox: As per the link in the answer: "An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted"

Comment: No, there is no 'sorting'. It will remember the order that keys were entered and return them in the same order each time. As you are specifically setting 'first' then 'second' then 'third' it will retain this order.